# loop through array to determine what main array will hold

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ok, so I have an array called posts[] that is a nsobject called Post. I am creating a function that makes sure a certain selected and saved postID: String will be saved in an array, then when the app relaunches those posts are not included in the main Feed. The user chooses what they want to see in their feed based on what they remove but not delete it (means the image is under the posters profile). But my main problem is I am when grabbing posts from firebase needing to loop through selectedArray["-postId", etc..] and check if a post value: postID, author, pathToImage (that is looped through following users posts) does not equal to one of the postID strings in the selectedArray. I have created a way to solve this (I thought) with a for each loop. The loop is below (please note that I commented out the loop and what I tried)

```
ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap)  in
    if snap.value != nil {
        let postSnap = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        for (_,post) in postSnap {
            if let userID = post["userID"] as? String {
                for each in self.following {
                    if each == userID {
                        var posst = Post()
                        //if let array = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "selected") as? [String] {                                
                        //for each1 in array {
                        // if posst.postID != each1 {
                        if let author = post["author"] as? String, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String {
                            posst.author = author
                            posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                            posst.postID = postID                                    
                            self.posts.append(posst)
                        }  
                    } else {
                        print("nope")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Alright, kinda a lot of code, but I hope you can see my goal, I have already created a function to get the postID of a selected image, put into the selected: Array, and save the array. My problem is I post 8 images to firebase and i ran the code and there were 4 postIds in selected, it produced 32 images, the for loop copied the post 4 times based on the for each loop. I am not to experienced I won't lie but how should I loop through this without creating 4 posts for each post when there are 4 items in the selected array. Please ask any questions, I'm here to answer.

Comment: Take your code into Xcode, select the entire block, and press Ctrl-i  You've got braces all over the places and some are missing.  Next spend some time reading in the Swift standard library about Array.filter and Array.contains.  If I understand what you are trying to do, I think those two methods might be helpful.

Comment: I also suggest you look into `Set`s